# AngularFireAuth.authState always emits a null value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to setup a route guard based on whether or not a user is logged in. I'm using AngularFireAuth (@angular/fire/compat/auth) and trying to read from it's `.authState`. I'm using `.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and I can see that I'm logged in from the firebase console. For whatever reason `.authState` always emits a null value (or so it appears). Here's my `canActivate` implementation:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.authService.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(console.log),
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }
```

I don't see anything logged from `tap`. I get this error in the console:

```
core.mjs:7739 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
    at Array.push (<anonymous>)
    at ObserverProxy.subscribe (index.esm2017.js:1665:24)
    at AuthImpl.registerStateListener (index-30f3030e.js:2575:33)
    at AuthImpl.onAuthStateChanged (index-30f3030e.js:2469:21)
    at Auth.onAuthStateChanged (index.esm2017.js:736:31)
    at angular-fire-compat-auth.js:99:138
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:25593:1)
    at Observable._subscribe (angular-fire-compat-auth.js:99:109)
```

("@angular/fire": "^7.5.0", "firebase": "^9.17.1", "@angular/core": "~13.3.12")

Answer (score 0):

you are using take A function that returns an Observable that emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable, or all of the values from the source if the source emits fewer than count values.
you should probably use takeLast.

takeLast results in an observable that will hold values up to count values in memory, until the source completes. It then pushes all values in memory to the consumer, in the order they were received from the source, then notifies the consumer that it is complete.

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeLast

the first count will be nill or undefined, I would also encourage you to turn this into an async promise.

```
async yourFunction():void {
  await this.authService.authState.pipe(
      takeLast(1),
      tap(console.log),
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      }),
      catchError((error) => if(error) return error)
    );
}
```

although I invoke Microsoft.com here - this function would work universally for any provider, I do not use angular fire I just use the native firebase library - if you use angular fire you just have to make a few small adjustments, I would recommend using firebase compat mode though because some of the web 9 code doesn't work as described.  I thought it prudent for others to see functioning code.

```
private authState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false as boolean);
public authState$ = this.authState.asObservable();
private user$ = new BehaviorSubject({} as any);
public user = this.user$.asObservable();



    signIn(){
        
        const auth = firebase.default.auth();
        
        const provider = new firebase.default.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
        provider.setCustomParameters({
          tenant: environment.microsoft.tenantid as string
        })
    
        provider.addScope('Mail.read');
        provider.addScope('Files.Read.All');
        provider.addScope('Files.ReadWrite.All');
        provider.addScope('Sites.Read.All');
        provider.addScope('Sites.ReadWrite.All');
        provider.addScope('User.Read.All');
        provider.addScope('User.ReadWrite.All');
        
        provider.addScope('Presence.Read');
        provider.addScope('Presence.Read.All');
    
        console.log(provider)
        auth.
        signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
       
          const credentials = result.credential;
         
          
          const user = result.user;
          // Get the OAuth access token and ID Token
          if(user?.uid != null){
    // store the user in a behavior subject
            this.user$.next(user)
    // call this behavior subject in another component to see if the user is authenticated.
            this.authState.next(true)
          }
        }).catch((error)=>{if(error) return error});
      }

if you are trying to use router guards:

     authenticated: boolean = false;
     constructor(private router:Router, private auth$:AuthService)
     async canActivate() {
        // console.log('GUARD START GUARD');
        // console.log('AUTHENTICATED', this.authenticated)
         this.auth$.authState$.subscribe(state=>{
          // console.log('can activate state',state)
          return this.authenticated=state
        });
     
        // console.log(this.authenticated)
              if (!this.authenticated) { 
                // window.alert('NOT LOGGED redirecting')
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
                return false;
              }
              else { 
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/account');
                return true;
              } 
    
      }
```